# Receiving blank user agent requests from HAProxy?

Tags: haproxy

My servers are receiving HTTP requests w/ blank user agents from my HAProxy load balancer.

The request headers are all the same:

```
Originating IP: Load Balancer IP
User Agent: Blank
Script: index.php
Headers:
Connection: close
Server IP
```

Is this a health check and if so, why is the user agent blank?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it wasn't HAProxy.
It was Varnish doing a health check w/ a blank user agent.